# Template of a class that contains a constant-type template?

Tags: c++, templates

## Situation

I'm trying to implement a container that holds a specific data type - let's call it C. The container(let's call it B) is an inner class of A. I'm trying to declare the template but am running into compiler issues and am not sure what I should do.

## Attempts

```
template <typename T<C>>
class A
{
    class B
    {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T> containerPtr;
    private:
        containerPtr container;
    }
}

typedef std::shared_ptr<A<std::vector<C>>> somePtr; // Error!
```

The error is:

> struct C
>
> type name is not allowed

---

```
template <typename T,U>
class A
{
    class B
    {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T<U>> containerPtr;
    private:
        containerPtr container; // But does it contain C or some other type now? 
        // We have to do a check - what's the best approach?
    }
}

typedef std::shared_ptr<A<std::vector<C>>> somePtr;
```

---

What is the best approach in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know for a fact that `T` is a template container storing some type `C`, then you don't need to specify `C` anywhere and can just templatize over `T`:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    class B {
       /* Use the type name T however you'd like. */
    };
};
```

This works because `T` has to be the name of a complete type, so if you do something like

```
A<std::vector<int>>
```

then `T` is `std::vector<int>` and any time you use `T` it will specifically be a `std::vector` of `int`s and not of any other type.

On the other hand, if you want the client to provide the name of a template class and then forcibly instantiate it with your choice of `C`, you can use *template template arguments*, like this:

```
template <template <typename...> class T>
class A {
    class B {
        typedef std::unique_ptr<T<C>> containerPtr;
        /* ... use containerPtr ... */
    };
};
```

This asks the user to give you a template type, so you'd write something like

```
A<std::vector> myObject;
```

and your `A` template will then instantiate `std::vector` using the type `C`.

Comment: Wow - I wanted to accept your answer even before you gave me the extra edited answer. You read my mind on what I wanted to do. Thank you very much! (I was trying to do the second approach but decided hesitantly that I'd just settle for the first) Could you explain what the `<typename...>` does?

Comment: @OneRaynyDay The general approach here is called a *template template argument* - we're providing a template as an argument to a template. The notation `template <typename...> class T>` means "the argument is a template class named `T`, and we don't care how many arguments that template class requires."

Comment: Ah, thank you! And thanks especially for telling me the name of the technique - I find that I get stuck with templates mainly because I don't know what to google. I really appreciate it.